# Windows 7 IPsec IKEv2 EAP-TLS error

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ssl, certificate, ipsec

I have set-up Strongswan on a Ubuntu 14.04 server from the official package repo with IKEv2 and rightauth=eap-tls using our PKI infrastructure. I can connect just fine from Android and Linux but not from Windows. I have installed my personal certificate in the certificate store but when trying to connect it throws this error in the image. I have also attached my certificate (without the private key obviously).

[image: vpn_error_pic]

[Certificate:](https://mega.co.nz/#!9UVUhDhT!ALAxAZqyMVwjlIQE8crMPUW__-JpNeWGQZcZoEV1Nro)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Is the private key installed? Did you install it in the system (_Computer account_) or the user (_My user account_) certificate store? Is the CA certificate installed too, and did you move it to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder?

Comment: I installed in in the User store, not Computer one. Our RootCA has been accepted by Microsoft for inclusion so it's in by default.